# Incorrect link in Swagger

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

I am using the ASP.NET Core 2.0 with Swashbuckle.AspNetCore (2.4.0)

in Startup ConfigureServices

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.OperationFilter<AuthorizationHeaderParameterOperationFilter>();
         c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info
            {
                Version = "v1",
                Title = "Library API",
                Description = "ASP.NET Core Web API",
                TermsOfService = "None",
                Contact = new Contact
                {
                    Name = "my name",
                    Email = "myname@mywebsite"
                }
            });
        });
      });
```

in Startup configure

```
          app.UseSwagger(c =>
        {
            c.RouteTemplate =
                "api-docs/{documentName}/swagger.json";
        });
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.RoutePrefix = "api-docs";
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("v1/swagger.json", "Api v1");
        });

 public class AuthorizationHeaderParameterOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
    {
        public void Apply(Operation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
        {
            var filterPipeline = context.ApiDescription.ActionDescriptor.FilterDescriptors;
            var isAuthorized = filterPipeline.Select(filterInfo => filterInfo.Filter).Any(filter => filter is AuthorizeFilter);
            var allowAnonymous = filterPipeline.Select(filterInfo => filterInfo.Filter).Any(filter => filter is IAllowAnonymousFilter);

            if (isAuthorized && !allowAnonymous)
            {
                if (operation.Parameters == null)
                    operation.Parameters = new List<IParameter>();

                operation.Parameters.Add(new NonBodyParameter
                {
                    Name = "Authorization",
                    In = "header",
                    Description = "access token",
                    Required = true,
                    Type = "string"
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

which looks like this

[image: localhost site]

however the links go to the url

```
about:blank
```

How do I set the v1/swagger.json link and the Terms of service link to go to the right place?

Comment: I have the same issue. It's a bug I think. If you use relative path in swagger endpoint (without '/') you will get such broken link. But swagger.json is available and all works.

Comment: That is the answer.     c.SwaggerEndpoint("./v1/swagger.json", "Api v1");  works. Care to write it up? @Alexey.Petriashev

Comment: The contact link also works now but not the Terms of service. Maybe that's because I left out the licence information.

Comment: I don't sure that my comment help you)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `c.SwaggerEndpoint("./v1/swagger.json", "Api v1");`

It's looks like a bug that relative path (without '/') renders empty link but swagger.json is available and all works.

I use relative path to work properly with reverse proxies but this is other story...